# How I find the total area of a triangle from the areas of three sections out of six created by concurrent lines one from each vertex?

Tags: math, geometry

In this triange:

[image]

Given the areas of triangles UPZ ZPW and WPY, how do you calculate the total area?

I've already found the solution from the available submissions at the website. But I want to know how to derive that solution.

```
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    // a is UPZ, b is ZPW, c is WPY

    double n = b*(a+b)*(a+b+c);
    double d = b*(a+b)-(a*c);

    cout << (n / d) ;
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics question, not a computer programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this question is kind of off topic, it is a geometry problem. The way to find the area of the big triangle UVW is to apply the link between areas and ratioes of lengths of the segments of the triangle UYW and then to apply Menelaus' theorem to derive the ratio
WY/WV which reveals the ratio between the areas of the triangle UYW and UVW.

Let `h_p` be the length of the height from point P to the edge UW. Then

```
a = UZ * h_p / 2   and   b = ZW * h_p / 2
```

Thus:

```
a / b = (UZ * h_p / 2) / (ZW * h_p / 2) = UZ / ZW
```

Let `h_W` be the length of the height from point W to the line UY

```
a + b = Area(WPU) = PU * h_W / 2   and   c = YP * h_w / 2
```

Thus:

```
c / (a + b) = (YP * h_W / 2) / (PU * h_W / 2) = YP / PU
```

By Menelaus' theorem for the triangle UWY and the line VZ, with P on VZ, we get:

```
1 = ( VW / VY ) * ( YP / PU ) * ( UZ / ZW ) = ( VW / WY ) * (c / (a + b)) * (a / b)
so  
VY / VW = (c * a) / ( b * (a + b))
```

and therefore:

```
WY / VW = 1 - (VY / VW) = 1 - (c*a) / ( b*(a + b)) = (a*b + b^2 - a*c ) / (a*b + b^2)
```

Let `h_U` be the length of the height from the point U to the edge VW. Then

```
Area(UVW) =  VW * h_U / 2
and
Area(UYW) = a + b + c = WY * h_U / 2
```

Hence

```
Area(UVW) / Area(UYW) = Area(UVW) / (a + b + c) = (VW * h_U / 2) / (WY * h_U / 2) = VW / WY
```

so

```
Area(UVW) / Area(UYW) = VW / WY = (a*b + b^2) / (a*b + b^2 - a*c)
Area(UVW) / Area(UYW) = Area(UVW) / (a + b + c) = (a*b + b^2) / (a*b + b^2 - a*c)
```

Finally, we obtain the formula:

```
Area(UVW) = (a + b + c) * (a*b + b^2) / (a*b + b^2 - a*c)
Area(UVW) = b * (a + b) * (a + b + c) / (b*(a + b) - a*c)
```